# Boost.Asio HTTP Server Session Closing

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a http server based on [Boost.Asio Example HTTP Server 2 (using an io_service-per-CPU design)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)

Each Request gets parsed, checked if it's a POST-Request, if Path is correct, if Content-Length Header is present, if one of these conditions is not correct, I generate a Bad-Request Response.

As everything is okay, I send a OK Response.

That's how it gets started.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    http::server s("127.0.0.1", "88", 1024);
    s.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now I made a quick C# app which starts 16 Threads and each Thread sends continuously in a while(true)-Loop POST-Requests to this server.

A while it runs smoothly and fast. Then at some point of time the server gets unresponsive (Cannot connect to remote server).

A cause for this could be that the sessions from the server don't get closed properly.

Here's the code for Bad-Request/OK Responses:

```
void session::handle_request()
{
  //Generate OK Response
  reply_ = reply::stock_reply(reply::ok);
  //Send OK Response
  boost::asio::async_write(client_socket_, reply_.to_buffers(), 
    boost::bind(&session::handle_client_write, shared_from_this(),
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void session::send_bad_request()
{
  //Generate Bad Request Response
  reply_ = reply::stock_reply(reply::bad_request);
  //Send Bad Request Response
  boost::asio::async_write(client_socket_, reply_.to_buffers(), 
    boost::bind(&session::handle_client_write, shared_from_this(),
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

And the handle_client_write which both trigger:

```
void session::handle_client_write(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t len)
{
  if (!err) {
    //Dummy Error Code Var
    boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
    //Shutdown socket
    client_socket_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored_ec);
    client_socket_.close();
    //std::cout << "Closed" << ignored_ec.message() << "\n";
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
  }
}
```

Like I said, at some point it gets unresponsive and after little time it responses again.

Comment: Monitor open sockets with some tool like TCPViewer, and see whether your assumption is correct or not. By the way, why don't you close the socket if `handle_client_write` gets called with error?

Comment: I put now the closing of the socket out of the if-else-clause. Your suggestions of TCPViewer was very helpful.. My C# App with 16 Threads without any sleep was just too much for Windows.. Thanks!